# Swap between monitor display modes using shortcut

Tags: shortcut-keys, multiple-monitors, display

I want to swap with a shortcut between 2 modes using dual monitor:

- Both display on
- Left display on
- Optionally, if only right display is on, turn both display on

This question was asked many times. However **all** sources found online are not accurate: there is always a small bit missing, e.g. command to detect which monitors are on is in fact used to detect which are connected; or the script is missing, etc.

So I combine all the answers here below.

To make this Q&A, I used the following sources (I might have forgot some):

1. To detect which monitors are on:

   - [How to list active displays (on command line)?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/412544/how-to-list-active-displays-on-command-line?rq=1)
2. To get the scripting:

   - https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2246932

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to your command line and create a .sh file (this will end up in home, I personnaly put them in a subfolder):

```
gedit ~/swap_monitors.sh
```

Copy & paste the following batch script. Note the `bash` call at the beginning, not `sh`

```
#!/bin/bash


## script to toggle between monitor modes

currentmonitor=$(xrandr | awk '/\ connected/ && /[[:digit:]]x[[:digit:]].*+/{print $1}')
double=$'DisplayPort-0\nHDMI-A-0'
right=$'DisplayPort-0'
left=$'HDMI-A-0'

if [ "$currentmonitor" = "$double" ]; then
    xrandr --output $left --auto --primary --output $right --off
elif [ "$currentmonitor" = "$right" ]; then
    xrandr --output $left --auto --primary --output $right --auto --right-of $left
else
    xrandr --output $left --auto --primary --output $right --auto --right-of $left
fi

exit 0
```

change the varibles `double`, `right` and `left` to the name of your monitors (check them with `xrandr -q`). Change the `xrandr` commands also if needed, e.g. perhaps you prefer primary on the right screen.

Note the `elif` conditions leads to the same command than after `else` so it is useless here. But I left it in case you want another behavior (e.g. circle between double>right>left>double>...)

Go to System Settings>keyboard panel (nautilus) and add the shortcut:

- name : Swap monitor mode
- command : /home/[username]/swap_monitors.sh

I personnaly added the shortcut Super+F4.

Answer (score 1):

It was helpful for me to do a similar thing using `arandr`

`sudo apt install arandr`
`arandr`

using the tool, you can configure a setup, then Layout > Save as... and name it to a run script like 'home_monitors_layout.sh' etc.

Then you can edit the script, or use the generated layout commands and plug it into the other answer provided here instead of manually configuring left/right/center/etc. layout

Comment: Plugging into the other answer - meaning setting up the shortcut in Settings > Keyboard (for me the "add shortcut" was at the bottom in 19.04). The default location created by arandr was /home/[username]/.screenlayout/[saved_setting].sh